# How do I append a blank row in a Google Spreadsheet with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I append/insert a blank/empty row in a google spreadsheet using app script?

I've tried:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("test");
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
sheet.appendRow(['Something']);
sheet.appendRow(['']);
sheet.appendRow(['Something Else']);
```

But this doesn't add a blank row.  The following doesn't work either (fails with an error):

`sheet.appendRow([]);`

A work around is to insert a space. But then this is not a truly blank row.

`sheet.appendRow([' ']);`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the usage of appending blank rows? For the user there's a button for that in the interface already, and for the script it does not matter, the rows are created automatically if needed.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu: I want a blank row in the output. I use blank rows all the time.  Hypothetical I suppose would be I want a row with a "Total: 5000" underneath a section of numbers but I want a blank row between the numbers and the total for aesthetic purposes.

Answer (score 6):

Google Scripts syntax has updated since the last of this post's answers.

To append a NULL or empty row,

```
// Add an empyty row after each file object:
var rowLast = newSpreadsheet.getLastRow();
newSpreadsheet.insertRowAfter(rowLast);
```

This is especially useful when working with file iterators/loops and printing results to a Google Sheet.

Best of luck.

Comment: Just a note that sheet must have at least one filled cell for this to work (I needed to add an empty row to an empty sheet and this wouldn't work.)

Answer (score 3):

consider:

```js
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
sheet.getRange('A' + nextRow )
.offset(0, 0, 3)
.setValues([ ['something'], 
             [''], 
             ['something else'] ]);
```

as it sets your new values all at once

Answer (score 3):

Using `insertRowsAfter` (in conjunction with `getMaxRows`) seemed to work for me:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("test");
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
sheet.appendRow(['Something']);

// Insert one empty row after the last row in the active sheet.
sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getMaxRows(), 1);

sheet.appendRow(['Something Else']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, seems it doesn't have a way to `append` an empty row. but if you want to add a row between them, you can try this.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 sheet.appendRow(['Something']);
 sheet.appendRow(['Something Else']);

 //add empty row between them
 var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
 sheet.insertRows(lastrow, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function addEmptyRow() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getDataRange();
   console.error(range)
   var values = range.getValues();
   for (var i = values.length; i>=1; i--) {
     if (values[i-1].join("")) {
       sheet.insertRowsAfter(i, 1);
       break
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

sheet.appendRow([null]);